# Remove Konqueror without installing firefox-esr from KDE Plasma in Debian

Tags: debian, kde, plasma, plasma5

I am trying to uninstall Konqueror from my Debian 11 system running KDE Plasma Desktop. Shell command `sudo apt remove konqueror` gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libkf5konq6
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  firefox-esr
Suggested packages:
  fonts-stix | otf-stix fonts-lmodern
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  konq-plugins konqueror
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox-esr
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 55.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 180 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I don't want firefox-esr to be installed because I am using Brave Browser which is already set to default.

Output of `apt-cache policy konq-plugins konqueror firefox-esr`:

```
konq-plugins:
  Installed: 4:20.12.0-4
  Candidate: 4:20.12.0-4
  Version table:
 *** 4:20.12.0-4 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
konqueror:
  Installed: 4:20.12.0-4
  Candidate: 4:20.12.0-4
  Version table:
 *** 4:20.12.0-4 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
firefox-esr:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 78.14.0esr-1~deb11u1
  Version table:
     78.14.0esr-1~deb11u1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     78.12.0esr-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
```

Also, I have no related metapackages installed. The only metapackage installed in my system according to synaptic is init.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.
Tried to remove konqueror using dpkg `sudo dpkg -r konq-plugins konqueror` and I found that libreoffice-help-en-us depends on either of firefox-esr, epiphany-browser, konqueror, chromium or firefox.

```
(Reading database ... 211190 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing konq-plugins (4:20.12.0-4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of konqueror:
 libreoffice-help-en-us depends on firefox-esr | epiphany-browser | konqueror | chromium | firefox; however:
  Package firefox-esr is not installed.
  Package epiphany-browser is not installed.
  Package konqueror is to be removed.
  Package chromium is not installed.
  Package firefox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package konqueror (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 konqueror
```

After removing libreoffice-help-en-us, I was able to remove konqueror.